# $X_i\sim \operatorname{Ber}(\theta_i)$ and $Y = \sum X_i$, sum of independent Bernoulli trials with different $\theta_i$. Find $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

$X_i\sim \operatorname{Ber}(\theta_i)$ and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, sum of independent Bernoulli trials with different $\theta_i$. So this is something like we have a collection of $n$ possibly unbalanced coins with a different chance $\theta_i$ of getting heads. Calculating the expected value of $Y$ was not so hard
$$\mu =E[Y] =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} E(X_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \theta_i = n\theta        ,$$
where $\theta  =   \frac1n\sum  _{i=1}^n   \theta_i   $. Finding the variance is harder though. Because all the $X_i$ are independent I just add the individual variances so:
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\theta_i(1-\theta_i)=n\theta -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \theta_i^2.$$

My book says it should equal $n\theta   (1-\theta) - \sum_{i=1}^n (\theta_i-\theta)^2  $. So maybe I am missing some algebra steps or maybe I did something wrong. If someone can tell me what I did wrong that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, since $n\theta =\sum \theta_i$

$\sum (\theta_i-\theta)^2= \sum (\theta^2 +\theta_i^2 -2\theta\theta_i)=\sum \theta_i^2 + n\theta^2 - 2\theta\sum \theta_i = \sum \theta_i^2 + n\theta^2 - 2n\theta^2 = \sum \theta_i^2 - n\theta^2$

You should certianly remember this trick. It will crop up again and again...

Comment: actually notice the variance is maximised when all of the $\theta_i = \theta$

Comment: Great, thanks :)